# PHP при парсинге записывает только последнее значение

Tags: php, циклы, phpquery

Нужно отпарсить каталог сайта, а именно название и описание товара. Использую библиотеку phpQuery. В самом начале я отпарсил все ссылки на страницу товара и поместил в файл $filename. Теперь мне нужно пройти по каждой ссылки из этого файла, взять инфу и поместить в файл $description. Написал цикл, так он почему-то записывает последнее значение в файл. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка

```
     $filename = "url.txt";
    $description = "description.txt";
    $lines = file($filename);
  foreach ($lines as $value) {
       $pageText =new Curl();
       $page=$pageText->get_page($value);
       $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($page);
       $select = $doc-> find("#ja-content-main > div > div > div.BlogItemDes-inner > div.TzArticleDescription > div.TzArticleIntrotext")->text();
       print $select;
       file_put_contents($description, $select, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: а вы попробуйте вывести переменную $select до того как записываете в файл.

Comment: К сожалению ничего не изменилось

Comment: А ничего и не должно было измениться, что содержится в переменной select при каждой итерации?

Comment: а ничего и не должно изменятся, я это к тому чтобы проверить приходят ли все данные, сделайте print_r($select); echo '<br>';

Comment: select хранит в себе текст описания товара

Comment: добавил print_r($select); echo '<br>'; Теперь он сделал число новых строк равное числу товаров, вывел и записал текст описания в файл

Comment: @CanistroBrandian А Вы уверены, что записывается только последнее значение, а не банально все значения в одну строку? Попробуйте добавить \n: `$select = $doc->...->text() . "\n";`

Comment: @Talgat Неа, проблема тоже не в этом. По итогу он в конце файла добавил новую строку

Comment: @CanistroBrandian похоже на то, что find не находит описание на странице.

Comment: @Talgat Видимо не правильно выразился. Он все также добавляет в файл тоже описание последнего товара из массива, но при этом добавил новую пустую строку

Comment: @CanistroBrandian А `print $select;` тоже выводит только последнее описание?

Comment: @Talgat Да выводит только последнее описание

Comment: @CanistroBrandian Значит либо find не находит, либо $lines содержит только 1 ссылку.

Comment: @Talgat Это я тоже проверял, lines имеет полный доступ к ссылкам

Comment: @CanistroBrandian Если Вы уверены, что foreach выполняет несколько итераций и при этом `print $select . " text";` выводит только слово text (и только в последней записи выводит описание + text), то копайте в сторону find. Ваш селектор не достаточно универсален.

Comment: @Talgat Так оно и есть. Сначала выводит просто text а в конце select и text/ Сейчас буду тестить

Comment: @Talgat В итоге и это не помогло. Опробовал разные вариации, причем селектор на всех страницах один и тот же

Comment: @CanistroBrandian А `get_page` по всем ссылкам контент получает? Проверяли, что у Вас в `$page` при каждой итерации? Попробуйте newDocumentHTML вместо newDocument. Посмотрите что выводит `echo pq('body').text();`

Answer (score 0):

Вы командой

```
$doc->find(...);
```

получаете **список** узлов. Применение к списку метода `text()` может давать произвольные результаты. Как я понимаю, автор библиотеки решил возвращать данные последнего узла.

У Вас должно быть как-то так

```
$nodes = $doc->find("#ja-content-main > div > div > div.BlogItemDes-inner > div.TzArticleDescription > div.TzArticleIntrotext");
foreach ($nodes as $item) {
  print $item-text();
  file_put_contents($description, $item->text(), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Нет. К сожалению все также выводит описание последнего товара из массива ссылок

Comment: @CanistroBrandian Значит остальные товары не попадают в этот селектор

Comment: Совпадают, я проверял. А обновленный способ выдает фата ерор. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::text()